# Associative algebras whose induced Lie algebras are reductive.

Tags: representation-theory, lie-algebras, associativity

Let $(A,\cdot)$ be a finte dimensional associative algebra over $\mathbb{C}$, which is noncommutative, and $(\mathfrak{g},[\cdot,\cdot])$ be its induced Lie algebra, i.e., $\mathfrak{g}= A$ as vector spaces and $[x,y]:=x\cdot y-y\cdot x,\forall x,y\in{A}.$ If

- the annihilator $ann(A):=\{x\in A:x\cdot y=y\cdot x=0,\forall y\in A\}$  is zero. (Note that there do exist associative algebras  having  non-trivial annihilator, for exmaple, nilpotent associative algebras).
- $(\mathfrak{g},[\cdot,\cdot])$ is a reductive Lie algebra, i.e., the adjoint
  representation ad$:\mathfrak{g}\rightarrow\mathfrak{gl}(\mathfrak{g})$ is completely reducible.

Then is  $(A,\cdot)$ necessarily a semisimple associative algebra? If not, are there any counterexamples?

Comment: Isn't $ker(L)=ker(R)=0$ automatically as soon as $A$ has a unit? So that e.g. $A=\mathbb{C}[x]/(x^2)$ is a counterexample? Do you maybe mean to assume that for each $a\in A$, the kernels of left and right multiplication with $a$ have trivial intersection?

Comment: Thanks, you are right.  The original question has been edited.

Comment: The left and right regular representations have zero kernel, as it has been said, so your first condition is weird.

Comment: The  first condition is equivalent to that the annihilator of A is zero. Note that nilpotent associative algebras necessarily have non-trivial  annihilator.

Comment: If your algebras are not unital, you should be explicit about that. Otherwise, only confusion ensues...

Comment: I don't see how the edit rules out the counter-example that @TorstenSchoeneberg mentions. Doesn't this answer your question?

Comment: Your edit including "noncommutative" (which I assume means "not *all* elements commute" i.e. $Z(A) \neq A$) rules out my immediate example $A_1 := \mathbb C[x]/(x^2)$ but e.g. $M_2(\mathbb C) \times A_1$ still works.

Comment: If you specifically want $A$ to be non-unital, you should say so in the question, and mention that for unital algebras, the first condition is empty. Also, the counterexample stands.

Comment: Thank you@Torsten Schoeneberg. It seems that associative algebras, with induced Lie algebras being reductive, are far from semisimple.

Answer (score 1):

Any such associative product $x\cdot y$ defines a *pre-Lie algebra structure* on the Lie algebra $\mathfrak{g}$. This means we have $(x,y,z)=(y,x,z)$ for the associator in the algebra $(A,\cdot)$, where $A$ and $\mathfrak{g}$ have the same underlying finite-dimensional vector space, and that $[x,y]=x\cdot y-y\cdot x$. If this product $x\cdot y$ is commutative, $\mathfrak{g}$ is the zero Lie algebra. We want to exclude this.

For the reductive Lie algebra $\mathfrak{gl}_n(\Bbb C)$, these
structures have been classified, see for example [here](https://homepage.univie.ac.at/Dietrich.Burde/papers/burde_04_reductive.pdf), and the references therein. Then the algebra $(A,\cdot)$ is simple, see Lemma $2$.

In general, it is an open problem, which complex reductive Lie algebras admit such a pre-Lie algebra structure (or an associative structure).

The example by Torsten is the $6$-dimensional algebra $A=M_2(\Bbb C)\times A_1$,
where $A_1$ has a basis $\{1,x\}$ with $1\cdot 1=1, 1\cdot x=x\cdot 1=x$ and $x\cdot x=0$. The algebra $(A,\cdot)$ is associative, but not commutative  and not semisimple. It has the reductive Lie algebra $\mathfrak{sl}_2(\Bbb C)\oplus \Bbb C^3$.

Comment: More Lie algebras admit pre-Lie structures than associative products inducing their products: it may well be the case that the problem of deciding which Lie algebras admit pre-Lie structures is much more difficult than the one of deciding which Lie algebras admit associative products, no?

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Álvarez Yes, the existence problem is much harder for pre-Lie in general. Still, the associative case is also not so easy. And a classification of the associative  structures might also be difficult.

Comment: @Torsten Schoeneberg has constructed a counterexample as above.

Comment: @zhanghtam Yes, thank you. I hope that the above references to pre-Lie algebra structures are still useful for you, for further questions on this topic.

Comment: Thank you for the references @Dietrich Burde

Answer (score 1):

To move this from comments to an answer, a nonabelian counterexample is given by

$$A = \mathbb C[x]/(x^2) \times M_2(\mathbb C) .$$